# Configure unable to find libgcrypt

Tags: linux, centos

hello i have faced problem with libgcrypt and i am sure is is installed with newst version thats happen when i try to install libssh2

```
[root@loft1034 libssh2-1.1]#./configure

configure: error: cannot find OpenSSL or Libgcrypt,
try --with-libssl-prefix=PATH or --with-libgcrypt-prefix=PATH
[root@loft1034 libssh2-1.1]# locate libgcrypt
/usr/lib/.libgcrypt.so.11.hmac
/usr/lib/libgcrypt.so.11
/usr/lib/libgcrypt.so.11.5.2
/usr/lib64/.libgcrypt.so.11.hmac
/usr/lib64/libgcrypt.so.11
/usr/lib64/libgcrypt.so.11.5.2
[root@loft1034 libssh2-1.1]#
```

i try to using prefix path with no benefit please help me?

Answer (score 23):

Install the package with the header files.

CentOS 6/7, perhaps Fedora:

```
sudo yum install -y libgcrypt-devel
```

Debian/Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install -y libgcrypt11-dev
```

Comment: And on debian/ubuntu/mint "libgcrypt-dev"

Comment: It's now `libgcrypt11-dev`

Comment: Could you please specify how to do so? Thanks!

Comment: Could you please specify how to do so? [2]

Comment: This does not work for CentOS 7. The command `sudo yum install libgcrypt-devel` works, but does not install static libraries.

Comment: yum search libgcrypt shows no such result:    mingw32-libgcrypt-static.noarch : Static library for mingw32-libgcrypt
                                : development
mingw64-libgcrypt-static.noarch : Static library for mingw64-libgcrypt
                                : development
libgcrypt.x86_64 : A general-purpose cryptography library
mingw32-libgcrypt.noarch : MinGW Windows gcrypt encryption library
mingw64-libgcrypt.noarch : MinGW Windows gcrypt encryption library

Comment: @AnuragSingh: Something is wrong on your system then; here's the direct link to the centos 7 x86_64 package: http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/libgcrypt-devel-1.5.3-14.el7.x86_64.rpm

Answer (score 0):

Try this (it works for Ubuntu 15.10 64 bit)

```
wget ftp://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libg/libgcrypt11/libgcrypt11_1.5.0-5+deb7u3_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libgcrypt11_1.5.0-5+deb7u3_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using centOS install `libcrypt-devel`:

```
sudo yum install libgcrypt-devel
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your answer to add some text explaining how this solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For ubuntu(works for me)

Try to download the package first, [download links](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libgcrypt11-dev), note choose the right architecture.

there take amd64 as an example.first we get the link address http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libg/libgcrypt20/libgcrypt11-dev_1.5.4-3+really1.8.1-4ubuntu1.3_amd64.deb

On ubuntu, we download the package

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libg/libgcrypt20/libgcrypt11-dev_1.5.4-3+really1.8.1-4ubuntu1.3_amd64.deb
```

then install it

```
sudo dpkg -i libgcrypt11-dev_1.5.4-3+really1.8.1-4ubuntu1.3_amd64.deb
```

Maybe there are other dependencies need to install.
you can choose to install it one by one, or follow the tips

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```